# 4 mysql table joins?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a complicated query (I think) and whether there is a better way of going about this, because clearly this is not working.

I have 4 tables and somehow need to join them. I need to get the red_value, blue_value, and green values from one table where the id of another table = {some number} and the layer = {some number}.

Here are the tables:

```
product_color:  
  **color_id (primary)**  
  red_value  
  green_value  
  blue_value  

set_color:  
  **setcolors_id(primary)**  
  **school_art_id (school_art -primary key)**  
  **baseimage_id (baseimage - primary key)**  
  **color_id (product_color - primary key)**  
  layer (same number value as the layer in the "baseimage"table)  

baseimage:  
  **id (primary key)**  
  layer (same value as layer in "set_color")

school_art:  
**id (primary key)**
```

Here is the code:

```
public function select_colors($value, $layer) {
global $db;
$result_array = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM set_colors
    INNER JOIN school_art ON set_colors.{$value} = school_art.id
    INNER JOIN base_product_color ON set_colors.color_id = base_product_color.color_id;
    INNER JOIN mbaseimage ON set_colors.baseimage_id = baseimage.id     
    WHERE set_colors.{$layer} = baseimage.layer
    "
);
return $result_array;
```

}

**So what I HOPE to do is to call the class and**

```
get the red_value, green_value and blue_value from the "product_color" table  
WHERE the "color_id" = the "color_id" of the "set_colors"  
and "school_art_id" = the {$value}
and "layer" = {$layer}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly?  
Does it not produce the right results? Is it too slow?

Comment: not getting any results. No error. but no results either

Comment: What values of `$value` and `$layer` are you passing to the function?

Answer (score 0):

You say "clearly this is not working". It is not clear what you mean by this. How did you arrive at this conclusion? Is it because you are joining 4 tables, and you regard this as a great many tables to join? I do not think 4 tables is a staggeringly large number of tables to join, particularly since you seem to be joining using primary keys. A better question would be whether the database design is normalised. Assuming that it is, I can't see any real problem with the posted query.

On the subject of normalisation, the column `layer` that appears in the tables `set_color` and `baseimage` appears to be redundant in one of those tables. Unless I've misunderstood what you're trying to communicate, it's an attribute dependent on the `baseimage_id` but it isn't an identifying attribute. So, it should be removed from one of those tables. If you're querying the table in which `layer` doesn't appear, and need to find out the value of `layer`, you need only join to the table where it is found.

EDIT:

```
WHERE set_colors.{$layer} = baseimage.layer
```

Is this really what you mean?